# OpenIdConnect: id token renewal when navigating to another site

Tags: authentication, .net-core, openid-connect

I use OpenIdConnect authentication in my .Net Core application (let's call it Site1). On one of the pages I have a link to another application (let's call it Site2). User is the same.
When user clicks on this link it should redirect to site2 without login prompt. It works fine till **id_token** is not expired, in my case this is 15 min. After this time login prompt is shown for site2 although user is still authorized on site1. It is ever possible to workaround this?

My idea is to make another call to **/connect/authorize** identity server endpoint anytime user is going to navigate to site but not sure if it will help. Something like this:

```
1. GET /connect/authorize?
    client_id=client1
    scope=openid api1
    response_type=id_token
2. navigate to site2
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.